# How to enable fullscreen in Jetpack Compose apps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

I'm learning [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) with Kotlin, and trying to make an app with the option to enable fullscreen mode in Android, only showing the status bar after swiping it down.

I've searched for examples online, but none of them worked for me yet.

Some can hide the status bar, but still left a black bar; some can display full screen UI, but the status bar contents are still there.

The default project gives me

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

what I've got is
[immersive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXjtl.jpg)

Then I added codes after `enableEdgeToEdge()`

```
val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
insetsController.apply {
    hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
    systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
}
```

What I've got is [the black status bar area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzyXK.jpg)

Comment: Have you read through [this example from Google?](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive) Or [this guide](https://www.droidcon.com/2024/01/15/camouflage-the-status-bar-with-edge-to-edge-jetpack-compose-screens-and-dialogs/) from January? Immersive mode can be tricky to implement perfectly, but if you need help, you'll need to show us your code first.

Comment: The keyword to look for ist "*edge to edge*".

Comment: I'm not sure if the code is enough to ask for help, now I have no idea to deal with it.@Holo